# Webkitdotnet printing issue

Tags: vb.net, webkit.net

I use webkitdotnet and vb.net for making a small browser,

I make it and when i use print button on browser it prints, but i want to print it from web side for ex.

```
<body onload="printdiv('printable_area')">
```

it does not get the command and it does not prints or show print dialog, The thing i want is

In a website is there a code for printing for ex. `<a hred="javascript:print()">Print</a>` or `<body onload="print()">` browser must print silently.

sorry for my english, its very bad.

Comment: Im confused, are you making a winforms app or a website? If the former and you have already worked out the code to print, just run that code when the page finishes loading.

Comment: Also i want to do that,
Browser works normal but when i use the javascript:print() in html it doesnot work!